# Customize ttk:button

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Hi,
I'm looking for a way to add a triangle in the corner right of my ttk::button like below :

[image]

Sometimes the same button execute 2 commands , I would like to specify him to my user by this symbol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need the images:

```
set imgred [image create photo -file redcorner.png]
set imggreen [image create photo -file greencorner.png]
```

Next create a style element for each of these colors:

```
ttk::style element create Red.Corner.TButton.indicator image $imgred
ttk::style element create Green.Corner.TButton.indicator image $imggreen
```

Now create the layouts for each of the two button styles.
The original ttk::button layout can be retrieved using

```
ttk::style layout TButton
```

We use this as a template and add in our indicator elements.

(**Edit**: note that different themes may have different layouts.
The example below is for the 'default' theme.)

```
ttk::style layout Red.Corner.TButton {
  Button.border -sticky nswe -border 1 -children {
    Button.focus -sticky nswe -children {
      Button.padding -sticky nswe -children {
        Button.label -sticky nswe 
        Red.Corner.TButton.indicator -side right -sticky ne}}}}


ttk::style layout Green.Corner.TButton {
  Button.border -sticky nswe -border 1 -children {
    Button.focus -sticky nswe -children {
      Button.padding -sticky nswe -children {
        Button.label -sticky nswe 
        Green.Corner.TButton.indicator -side right -sticky ne}}}}
```

Now all the pieces are in place to create your buttons:

```
ttk::button .b -text hello -style Red.Corner.TButton
```

To change the indicator color, simply re-configure using the other style:

```
.b configure -style Green.Corner.TButton
```

References: [ttk::style](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_style.htm)

Comment: Nice. Can you please add it to the Wiki? I find ttk styling one of the most difficult aspects of Tcl/Tk: good tutorials are valuable.

Comment: thank you so much @Brad , I changed **Button.border -sticky nswe -border 1 -children** by **Button.button -sticky nswe -children** for vista theme.

Comment: A very good point.   I tested the above on Linux, so the layouts are for the X11 interface.

Comment: I should have said the layout above is for the 'default' theme.   Each theme may have a different layout.